# Heroku won't start django app

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I have a valid Procfile

```
web: gunicorn Likenohaters.wsgi --log-file -
```

In the heroku log i get the following error:

```
17:09:59 web.1  | usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]

17:09:59 web.1  | gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: --access-logfile-
```

It should have been "--access-logfile -", but somehow it lost the space. I only added some env vars and didn't change the code. Can it be a bug?

On local, with 'heroku local -f Procfile' it works.

Comment: What are the vars? Do any of them contain '//'?

Comment: Yes! One var contains a url

Comment: @Cucu Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to be bash related. There might be some restrictions in place. I'll try removing the url var.

Comment: By chance, are you using honcho ?

Comment: For the development setup I am using honcho because I have a background worker.